# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Am trying Retrofit to get this response

```
POST : https://wrlyxhnjw3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/pacakageinfo
BODY : {"type":"carwash"}
```

**Response**

```
[
  {
    "title": "SEDAN/NON SEDAN Exterior",
    "choice": "Exterior Only",
    "price": "$29.95/34.95 +",
    "description": [
      "Full body waterless car wash",
      "Windows & Mirrors cleaning",

    ],
    "addons": [
      {
        "price": "29.95",
        "title": "Sedan 29.95$ USD"
      },
      {
        "price": "34.95",
        "title": "Non-Sedan SUV 34.95$ USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "SEDAN/NON SEDAN",
    "choice": "Exterior & Interior",
    "price": "$34.95/44.95 +",
    "description": [
      "Full body waterless car wash",
      "Leather cleaning & Care"
    ],
    "addons": [
      {
        "price": "34.95",
        "title": "Sedan 34.95$ USD"
      },
      {
        "price": "44.95",
        "title": "Non-Sedan/SUV 44.95$ USD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**PackagesAPI Class**

```
public interface PackagesAPI {
    @POST("/prod/pacakageinfo")
    Call<List<PackagesAdapter.Item>> loadPackages(@Body PackagesFragment.PackageType packageType);
}
```

**GetPackagecall** *(In a Package Fragment)*

```
private void getPackagesCall(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://wrlyxhnjw3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        PackagesAPI packagesAPI = retrofit.create(PackagesAPI.class);
        Call<List<PackagesAdapter.Item>> call = packagesAPI.loadPackages(new PackageType("carwash"));
        call.enqueue(this);
    }
public class PackageType {
    final String type;

    PackageType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**Public Objects** *in class PackageAdapter*

```
public class Item {
    String title;
    String choice;
    String price;
    public List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<Addon> addons = new ArrayList<Addon>();
}
public class Addon {
    String price;
    String title;
}
```

But it gives "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path" exception?

I saw other posts like this and generally there's an issue with object definitions?

Am not able to figure out what's wrong here, I tried [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Comment: Hi, try making `Item`and `Addon` to be `static` or move them into their own classes - I am suspecting this might be the issue. Please try and let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla yes it resolved after making their individual objects public like `public String title` . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  try and make `Item` and `Addon` classes to be `static` or move them into their own class definitions (out of `PackageAdapter`). So in this solution, I am assuming that you move these classes to their separate class files/definitions if there are no compelling reasons for having them as inner classes.

**In** `Item.java:`

```
public class Item {
    String title;
    String choice;
    String price;
    public List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<Addon> addons = new ArrayList<Addon>();
}
```

**In** `Addon.java`

```
public class Addon {
    String price;
    String title;
}
```

Instead of making the member variables to be `public`, please try moving either making these inner classes to be `static`, or move them to separate class files (recommended). Test it out and let us know if it solves the problem.